# Samsung Galaxy S6 not booting to TWRP

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

After flashing the 3.3.1 twrp image to my S6 (SM-G920F)

After TWRP is downloaded, I switch off with (vol down and power)
When the phone is off (holding vol up + home + power, releasing power after the logo is visible)
I can see the TWRP Logo for a second, but then phone restarts into stock OS.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to upgrade the stock OS to the newest version. Even after that the installed Telekom AG branded OS did not receive the newest patches. Using an older TWRP (3.2.x instead of 3.3.x) version did the trick.